# How can i count number of black spaces in scikit image or mahotas?

Tags: image-processing, numpy, scikit-image, mahotas

i have an image like this:

[image: star]

after I skeletonize it by scikit image's skeletonize  function

```
from skimage import morphology
out = morphology.skeletonize(gray>0)
```

[image]

There is a way for counting the number of black spaces? (in this picture six) except the background in scikit-image or mahotas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this input:

[image: enter code here]

You can do:

```
>>> from skimage import morphology
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.misc import imread
>>> im = imread("Bju1h.png")
>>> im = im > 0
>>> np.unique(morphology.label(im))
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
>>> num_components = len(np.unique(morphology.label(im))) - 2
>>> num_components
6
```

I subtract 2 to ignore the background component and the foreground/line component. From your original image you can skip out the skeletonize step and just run this with `im = gray > 0`, since the wide foreground/line will still be labelled as a single component.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion why i get: [0 1], num_components: 2; I tried also with other images. I skeletonized the image because i need it for other stuffs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Do you have any suggestion why i get: [0 1], num_components: 2;".

Comment: I do not figure out why after skeletonization i get always  [0 1], num_components: 2, and before it works well! I need the components number after skeletonization!

Comment: Rigbht. The problem is in pixel connectivity. If you look at how [`label`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.label) decides whether pixels are connected, if you choose 8-connected regions, it will spill over thin jagged boundaries and if you choose  4-connected regions you will get too many regions as there will be multiple labels for the foreground. This problem did not appear in the input I used above as the image was blown up and jpeg compressed originally. I can post a fudge to get around this, but...

Comment: ...you should just count the components before the skeletonization operation to avoid the hassle.

Comment: Also, in the image you posted, most of the black pixels are not fully black, which causes problems in the thresholding/skeletonization step. I think this is caused at least in part by the jpeg compression - best to save in PNG form.

Comment: If i use a background subtraction for solving thresholding/skeletonization step instead of change format file ? Does it make sense? http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_regional_maxima.html

Comment: You can also do edge detection (Sobel with an appropriate sigma) + edge thresholding + dilation and then count the label areas--that might be a bit more robust.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with scipy.ndimage alone

```
from  scipy import ndimage as nd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

star = nd.imread('/home/jeanpat/Images/star.jpg')
star = star[:,:,0]
thr = star < 120
anti = star >119
mask = nd.morphology.binary_fill_holes(thr)

lab, n = nd.label(anti*mask)
plt.title(str(n)+' objects detected')
plt.imshow(lab)
plt.show()
```

[image]